# Setting some notifications with AlarmManager and cancelling one of them

Tags: java, android

in my program i set notifications with  a string and its clock to get a notification with that string at its clock.(I mean user wants to get a notification with a string at demanding time, and user gave me a lot of strings and their clocks.) And if the user want to cancel that notification i don't know how to do it.

I tried alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent) but I want to cancel the only one notification not all of them. Also, it doesn't cancel any notification too.

here is the code in the main

```
public void gecikmeliGoster(String plan, int yil, int ay, int gun, String saat){

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        NotificationManager bildirimYoneticisi = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent ıntent = new Intent(HatirlaticiKur.this, AlarmReciever.class);

        PendingIntent gidilecekIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, ıntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String kanalId = "kanalId";
            String kanalAd = "kanalAd";
            String kanalTanım = "kanalTanım";
            int kanalOnceligi = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            NotificationChannel kanal = bildirimYoneticisi.getNotificationChannel(kanalId);

            if (kanal == null) {
                kanal = new NotificationChannel(kanalId, kanalAd, kanalOnceligi);
                kanal.setDescription(kanalTanım);
                bildirimYoneticisi.createNotificationChannel(kanal);
            }

            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, kanalId);

            builder.setContentTitle("Hatırlatıcı")
                    .setContentText(plan)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.hatirlatici)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(gidilecekIntent);
        } else {

            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            builder.setContentTitle("Hatırlatıcı")
                    .setContentText(plan)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.hatirlatici)
                    .setContentIntent(gidilecekIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        }
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(HatirlaticiKur.this, AlarmReciever.class);

        broadcastIntent.putExtra("nesne", builder.build());

        PendingIntent gidilecekBroadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //long gecikme = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000; //bu 5 saniyede bir bildirim gelmesi için falan
        String[] noktasiz = saat.split(":");
        int akrep = Integer.parseInt(noktasiz[0]);
        int yelkovan = Integer.parseInt(noktasiz[1]);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, yil);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, ay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, gun);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, akrep);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, yelkovan);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 0, gidilecekBroadcast);

}
```

and here is the code in AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager bildirimYoneticisi = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification bildirim = intent.getParcelableExtra("nesne");

    bildirimYoneticisi.notify(1,bildirim);

}



}
```

I want to cancel demanding notifications, i will appreciate your help

Comment: Please only use the tag android-studio for questions referring to the IDE Android-Studio.

Answer (score 0):

use used 0 id for setting alarm

```
 PendingIntent gidilecekBroadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

You need uniqueid for all notification set using alarmmanager
then based on uniqueid you can cancel alarm

```
PendingIntent gidilecekBroadcast  = 
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), uniqueid , broadcastIntent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
alarmManager.cancel(gidilecekBroadcast);
```